# Python Log File is not created unless basicConfig is called on top before any functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, ini

I have a script that processes csvs and load them to database. My intern mentor wanted us to use log file to capture what's going on and he wanted it to be flexible so one can use a config.ini file to edit where they want the log file to be created. As a result I did just that, using a config file that use key value pairs in a dict that i can extract the path to the log file from. These are excepts from my code where log file is created and used:

```
dirconfig_file = r"C:\Users\sys_nsgprobeingestio\Documents\dozie\odfs\venv\odfs_tester_history_dirs.ini"
start_time = datetime.now()

def process_dirconfig_file(config_file_from_sysarg):
    try:
        if Path.is_file(dirconfig_file_Pobj):
            parseddict = {}
            configsects_set = set()
            for sect in config.sections():
                configsects_set.add(sect)
                for k, v in config.items(sect):
                    # print('{} = {}'.format(k, v))
                    parseddict[k] = v
            print(parseddict)
            try:
                if ("log_dir" not in parseddict or parseddict["log_dir"] == "" or "log_dir" not in configsects_set):
                    raise Exception(f"Error: Your config file is missing 'logfile path' or properly formatted [log_file] section for this script to run. Please edit config file to include logfile path to capture errors")
    except Exception as e:
        #raise Exception(e)
        logging.exception(e)
        print(e)

parse_dict = process_dirconfig_file(dirconfig_file)
logfilepath = parse_dict["log_dir"]
log_file_name = start_time.strftime(logfilepath)
print(log_file_name)
logging.basicConfig(
    filename=log_file_name,
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='[Probe Data Quality] %(asctime)s - %(name)s %(levelname)-7.7s %(message)s'
    # can you explain this Tenzin?
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    try:
        startTime = datetime.now()
        db_instance = dbhandler(parse_dict["db_string"])
        odfs_tabletest_dict = db_instance['odfs_tester_history_files']
        odf_history_from_csv_to_dbtable(db_instance)
        #print("test exception")
        print(datetime.now() - startTime)
    except Exception  as e:
        logging.exception(e)
        print(e)
```

Doing this, no file is created. The script runs with no errors but no log file is created. I've tried several things including using a hardcoded log file name, instead of calling it from the config file but it didn't work

The only thing that works is when the log file is created up top before any method. Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure this code runs? Your inner `try` should raise a `SyntaxError` without a matching `except` block

Comment: @C.Nivs it works. To save y'all from unneccasry code, i only did very minimal extract. But yes the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling your `process_dirconfig_file` function, the logging configuration has not been set yet, so no file could have been created. The script executes top to bottom. It would be similar to doing something like this:

```py
import sys

# default logging points to stdout/stderr kind of like this
my_logger = sys.stdout

my_logger.write("Something")

# Then you've pointed logging to a file
my_logger = open("some_file.log", 'w')

my_logger.write("Something else")
```

Only `Something else` would be written to our `some_file.log`, because `my_logger` pointed somewhere else beforehand.

Much the same is happening here. By default, the `logging.<debug/info>` functions do nothing because `logging` won't do anything with them without additional configuration. `logging.error`, `logging.warning`, and `logging.exception` will always at least write to stdout out of the box.

Also, I don't think the inner `try` is valid Python, you need a matching `except`. And I wouldn't just print an exception raised by that function, I'd probably `raise` and have the program crash:

```py
def process_dirconfig_file(config_file_from_sysarg):
    try:
        # Don't use logging.<anything> yet
        ~snip~
    except Exception as e:
        # Just raise or don't use try/except at all until
        # you have a better idea of what you want to do in this circumstance
        raise
```

Especially since you are trying to use the logger while validating that its configuration is correct.

The fix? Don't use the logger until after you've determined it's ready.

Comment: So I took the config out of the config file but because I call the logger in that process_dir_config function, it doesn't wirte to it. So it appears I need to have the config file created before that function. I say this because the script is gonna be run in a server environment so the only way the user will know what went wrong is to open a log file.

Comment: The inner exception is there, i just left it out of the code. But yes I discoverd the cause just now and thank you for the additional background info. 

I moved the log info out of the config file but as long as the log config is created after the process function, it never creates a log file. Is this because unless there is an exception in the main function, nothing would be written and therefore no log file would appear?

Comment: The file should always populate when you set up the logger. You can see for yourself by just doing `logging.basicConfig(filename='myfile.log')`, which will create an empty file `myfile.log`. So if an exception is raised before the program can get to the logging setup, then no file will be created

Comment: In this situation, it appears no file is created unless an error occurs